# linguex and multicols

Tags: multicol, linguex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}\raggedcolumns
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\ex. Shouldn't/Didn't he $\dots$?\\*
\ex. Shouldn't/Didn't she $\dots$?\\*
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Hi, I keep getting error messages when I embedded `\ex.` into `multicols`. Is there any way to avoid these errors?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's caused by wrong input of the code

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake. 
The list environment created by \ex. must be closed by a single blank line (a \par).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}\raggedcolumns
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ex. Shouldn't/Didn't he $\dots$?

% An empty line must be inserted.
\ex. Shouldn't/Didn't she $\dots$?
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```